# TinyMCE disable link navigation in design mode

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

I'm wondering how to disable ctrl-clicking links when in design mode. I believe it must be possible because when the link plugin is disabled, links cannot be ctrl-clicked while in 'design' mode. I would like to enable the link plugin but have the links remain un-clickable while in 'design' mode. They can still be clicked when in 'readonly' mode.

This fiddle shows the functionality when the link plug in is not enabled. Just use the Add Link button to add a link to the editor and notice when you're in design mode how it cannot be ctrl-clicked to navigate.

https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/Q6haab/3

This fiddle has the link plugin enabled to show the difference of ctrl-clicking while in edit mode.

https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/Q6haab/4

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you import the link plugin there is currently no way to disable the link opening behavior with configuration.

TinyMCE registers event handlers for [click and keydown](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/develop/modules/tinymce/src/plugins/link/main/ts/core/Actions.ts#L64) which check for the click on the link.

Additionally the link plugin registers menu items that are displayed on [right click for opening the link](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/develop/modules/tinymce/src/plugins/link/main/ts/ui/Controls.ts#L145).

Ultimately these all call the [same method](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/develop/modules/tinymce/src/plugins/link/main/ts/core/OpenUrl.ts#L14) which creates an anchor tag on the body and fires a mouse click event on it.

If you wish to stop clicking from doing anything then you can add an event listener to the body tag for click events and then filter on the event target to look for anchor tags that are directly on the body and have 3 attributes (`href`, `rel` and `target`). Once you find a likely candidate you call `preventDefault` on the event.

```js
body.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  const t = evt.target;
  if (
      t.parentNode === body &&
      t.attributes.length === 3 &&
      t.hasAttribute('href') &&
      target.getAttribute('rel') === 'noreferrer noopener' &&
      t.getAttribute('target') === '_blank') {
    evt.preventDefault()
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks James, a variation of this is what I ended up going with.